# Phpunit token storage error during test

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

I have a test file to test services instantiation and i have made a custom menu with KnpMenuBundle. 
Everything is working expect phpunit who return an error when testing my MenuBuilder.

There is the function who test all services instantiation my test file :

```
class ServiceAvailabilityTest extends KernelTestCase
{
    /**
    * @dataProvider getServiceIds
    *
    * @param $serviceId
    */
    public function testServiceInstance($serviceId)
    {
        static::bootKernel();

        static::$kernel->getContainer()->get($serviceId);
    }
}
```

On my MenuBuilder i use authorizationChecker to know if the user is granted or not, like this.

```
if ($this->authorizationChecker->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')) {
    $menu->addChild('sidebar.front.administration', ['route' => 'sonata_admin_redirect'])
         ->setExtra('translation_domain', 'navigation')
         ->setAttribute('icon', 'fa fa-eye');
}
```

When i'm removing all this, tests are ok

```
$this->authorizationChecker->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')
```

There is the error i get when i run phpunit

> 1) Tests\ServiceAvailabilityTest::testServiceInstance with data set #423 ('menu.main')
>       Symfony\Component\Security\Core\ExceptionAuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: The token storage contains no authentication token. One possible reason may be that there is no firewall configured for this URL.    /code/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authorization/AuthorizationChecker.php:57
>       /code/src/AppBundle/Menu/MenuBuilder.php:192
>       /code/src/AppBundle/Menu/MenuBuilder.php:101
>       /code/app/cache/test/appTestDebugProjectContainer.php:8311
>       /code/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php:312
>       /code/tests/ServiceAvailabilityTest.php:3

There is my menu services if you have to check them

```
menu.builder:
    class: AppBundle\Menu\MenuBuilder
    arguments: [ '@knp_menu.factory', '@doctrine', '@manager.server','@security.authorization_checker', '@request_stack' ]

menu.main:
    class: Knp\Menu\MenuItem
    factory: [ '@menu.builder', 'createMainMenu' ]
    arguments: [ '@request_stack' ]
    tags:
        - { name: knp_menu.menu, alias: sidebar }
```

I already search on the internet but they fix this by adding an access control on security.yml like this

```
- { path: ^/, role: ROLE_USER }
```

But i don't have any route for a menu.

Does someone already had this phpunit error ?
Thanks,

Comment: Did you try this?  http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/testing/http_authentication.html

Comment: OK, thanks, i will try

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
/**
 * @param string        $firewallName
 * @param UserInterface $user
 * @param array         $options
 * @param array         $server
 */
protected function loginUser($firewallName, UserInterface $user, array $options = array(), array $server = array())
{
    $this->client = static::createClient();

    $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, $firewallName, $user->getRoles());
    static::$kernel->getContainer()->get('security.token_storage')->setToken($token);
    // <2.8 this may be usefull
    //$request = new Request();
    //$event = new InteractiveLoginEvent($request, $token);
    //static::$kernel->getContainer()->get('event_dispatcher')->dispatch('security.interactive_login', $event);

    $session = $this->client->getContainer()->get('session');
    $session->set('_security_'.$firewallName, serialize($token));
    $session->save();
    $cookie = new Cookie($session->getName(), $session->getId());
    $this->client->getCookieJar()->set($cookie);
}
```

in your testCase/setUp for example::

```
static::bootKernel();
$this->loginUser('admin', $testUser);
$this->assertNotFalse(static::$kernel->getContainer()->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN'));
```

Comment: This give me the error `Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 2 passed to Tests\ServiceAvailabilityTest::loginUser() must implement interface Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface, null given, called in /code/tests/ServiceAvailabilityTest.php on line 46 and defined
`

Comment: the messages pretty much says what you are doing wrong. you need a userobject which you give to loginUser this user object must implement the UserInterface. (which should be so if you use a doctrine user provider for example)

Comment: Yes, I put a new user who removed this error. Thanks.